# (scan-error "Unbalanced parentheses" 1 1) when stepping forward in Edebug

Tags: debugging, error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (scan-error "Unbalanced parentheses" 1 1)
  scan-lists(41 -1 -1)
  down-list(-1)
  edebug-step-out()
  edebug-forward-sexp(1)
  funcall-interactively(edebug-forward-sexp 1)
  command-execute(edebug-forward-sexp record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "edebug-forward-sexp" nil)
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "edebug-forward-sexp" nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
  recursive-edit()
  debug(debug)
  debug--implement-debug-on-entry()
  apply(debug--implement-debug-on-entry nil)
* find_last_ontology_file()
  (progn (find_last_ontology_file))
```

When I try to step forward from the entrypoint `find_last_ontology_file` using `debug-on-entry`, I get the above error. But where exactly would I have mismatched parentheses? The code works without throwing parentheses-related errors when I'm not debugging. The code is below, if it helps.

```
(defmacro dowhile (body condition)
  (cons 'progn  body)
  (list 'while condition (cons 'progn body)))

     
(defun file-exists-in-buffer-directory (filename)
 (let* ((buffer-directory (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))
        (full-path (concat (file-name-as-directory buffer-directory) filename)))
   (file-exists-p full-path)))

    

(defun find_last_ontology_file ()
  (let ((current_file (car (split-string buffer-file-name "\\.")))
        (index 1)
        (last_found_ont_file nil)
        (keep_looping t))

       (dowhile
        ((let ((filename_to_check (concat current_file "_" (number-to-string index) ".pu")))
          (if (file-exists-in-buffer-directory filename_to_check)
          (progn (setq index (1+ index))
                 (setq last_found_ont_file filename_to_check))
          
          (setq keep_looping nil))))
          keep_looping)

        (if last_found_ont_file
            last_found_ont_file
            nil)))
(find_last_ontology_file)
```

Comment: Start by formatting your code better, please. And start by getting rid of the extra code in your macro - it does nothing.

Comment: @Drew sorry, did a bit of reformating. Would you happen to know if there are any Elisp linters for formatting? (Also: the macro is invoked once)

Comment: `C-h k  C-M-q` for indentation. `show-paren-mode` for parenthesis matching.